# Hive Timestamp value change after joining two tables

Tags: hadoop, timestamp, hive

I have two Hive tables, one holds a date value with Timestamp datatype. If I query on one specific record using the key it shows the date value correctly.
  select acct_key, account_open_date from Table_1 where acct_key=1234;

```
 acct_id   account_open_date
 1234      1963-03-01 00:00:00
```

However when joining this table with another table, the returned timestamp value changed to some value in year 2031
select a.acct_key, b.account_open_date
from Table_2 a left outer join on Table_1 b
on a.acct_key=b.acct_key;

```
acct_id    account_open_date
 1234       2031-03-19 00:00:00
```

Seems this issues only occurs for date value before Unix epoch time(1970). Any suggestion? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Two issues here, first thing join not working with timestamp and epoch timestamp. With your last line, I assume that the join is returning correct timestamp for other timestamp. Correct me if I am wrong. So if that is resolved, you can look into [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-DateFunctions) to handle epoch time

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to reproduce what you are seeing but nonetheless, you could try casting `account_open_date` to `string`.

```
select a.acct_id
    , b.new
    , other_columns
from db.table1
left outer join (
  select *
    , cast(account_open_date as string) new
  from db.table2 ) b
on a.acct_id=b.acct_id
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Wondering instead of using a nested query, can I directly do cast as string as below. Is there difference between these two?                                                                                                                                                                        select a.acct_id
    , cast(b.account_open_date as string) new
    , other_columns
from db.table1 a,
left outer join db.table 2 b
on a.acct_id=b.acct_id;

Comment: As stated above, I couldn't reproduce what you were seeing but I was assuming that somehow during the `join`, the timestamp column was being altered.  So I did `cast` then `join`.  I don't think there would be much of a performance difference if that is what you are worried about.

Answer (score 0):

I tried. Cast timestamp as String in a nested query worked as below. I also tried without nested query, but that does not work. Anyone knows why?

Not worked version:

```
SELECT 
   a.acct_id
  ,CAST(b.account_open_date AS STRING) new
  ,other_columns 
FROM 
  db.table1 a, 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN db.table2 b ON (a.acct_id = b.acct_id)
;
```

worked version:

```
SELECT 
     a.acct_id
    ,b.new
    ,other_columns
FROM 
    db.table1 a
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (
        SELECT 
           *
          ,CAST(account_open_date AS STRING) new
       FROM 
          db.table2
    ) b
       ON (a.acct_id=b.acct_id)
```